# contact 'name' can not be filtered in a query call

Tags: apex, soql, dynamic-soql

I tried to run this query and got the error as **'name' can not be filtered in a query call**. The query is **[select id,name from contact where name like '%test%']** . The result is varying from org to org. I tried in my developer edition and it is working fine. when I try this is in my project sandbox and I got the mentioned error.

Comment: Is Name field encrypted in your project sandbox. Like are you using Salesforce Shield implementation?

Comment: how do I know that field is encrypted. because when I use soql as plain like [select id,name from contact where firstname != null] . it is working totally fine. but I cannot use the like operator

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in my comment the encryption fields cannot be used in the
filter criteria . You cannot use those field in Aggregate functions such as **MAX()**, **MIN()**, and **COUNT_DISTINCT()**,**WHERE** clause,**GROUP BY** clause,**ORDER BY** clause as well.

You may have to remove the encryption to use them in the above scenarios. Please find the below [article](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.security_pe_considerations_general.htm&type=5) from Salesforce which explains the same .

Comment: is there any other way other than removing  the encryption?

Comment: There was a tip in the  above article saying to  Consider whether you can replace a WHERE clause in a SOQL query with a FIND query in SOSL.

Answer (score 0):

I came to know that the field is encrypted and I removed the encryption for contact name field and the query is working now.